# How to show a cell formula with cell values instead of cell references?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

If I have a cell formula such as that in A4.... “=A1+A2”

I know I can use the FORMULATEXT() function to display the formula in cell B4 but I do not want the formula to show cell references.

Instead, I want the to create in cell C4 a method to display the formula from cell A4, but showing the values instead of cell references so “=5+10” as the final result.  If I change A1 to 6, the resulting display in C4 would be “=6+10”.

The reason is I want my Excel formulas to be checkable on the printed page.  Cell references are of no use.  I want to see the values.  I need this to be able to be applied to hundreds of formulas.  So I hope for some VBA for a user def function I can add to the cell similar to FORMULATEXT() except instead of cell references, I need values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you hope for some VBA you should include your own code/attempt.

Comment: dunno if the answers here will help or not but worth checking out https://superuser.com/questions/1515531/opposite-of-formulatext-in-excel

Comment: Why do you want to check formulas on a printed page? There are features built in to Excel to make formula auditing much simpler.

Comment: I would like some VBA but I am a novice and wouldn’t even know where to start.  I am an engineer and need to be able to turn over calcs to another engineer for checking or files are often just a PDF so it’s better to have paper checkable calcs.

Comment: You definitely won't be able to get to this goal using a worksheet function. VBA UDF's are simpler than you think; a couple of quick Google (or SO) searches for "how to implement Excel user defined functions" will get you the basics.

Comment: Has anyone developed a UDF I could “borrow”/have that does what I am looking for?

Comment: Hello anyone please help?  Is this possible?  Is it just very difficult/complicated?  I don’t mind buying an Addin if someone knows of one that will do what I need.

Comment: Its a Duplicate Question.
May be this will help you. <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579748/excel-how-to-display-values-in-cell-formula-instead-of-references">Excel, how to display values in cell formula instead of references</a>

Comment: Well it’s a duplicate to a question from 8 years go with 37k views and no acceptable answer.  I guess this is not possible or too difficult to code.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Excel works; if you have a formula in a cell, that is what is going to show up in the formula bar.

EDIT

You can use VBA (from `Tools > Macros > Visual Basic Editor`), however, to write code that will update the contents of the C cells with the the values of A + B, like this:

```
Private Sub HideFormula()
    Dim lastrow As Long, r1 As Long

    ' Get the last row in the worksheet
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For r1 = 1 To lastrow

        ' If A & B aren't blank, make the formula of cell C equal to A + B.
        If Sheet1.Range("$A$" & r1).Value <> "" And _
            Sheet1.Range("$B$" & r1).Value <> "" Then

            ' In the example, C2 = A1 + B1, so offset C by one
            Sheet1.Range("$C$" & (r1 + 1)).Value = _
                "=" & Sheet1.Range("$A$" & r1).Value & "+" & _
                Sheet1.Range("$B$" & r1).Value

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

EDIT 2

If you want to replace the contents of a C cell with the values in the formula, you can use the `.Formula` value to find its formula, and go from there:

```
Private Sub ReplaceFormulaWithValues()
    Dim lastrow As Long, r1 As Long
    Dim temp As String, arTemp

    ' Get the last row in the worksheet
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For r1 = 1 To lastrow

        ' If A & B aren't blank, make the formula of cell C equal to A + B.
        If Sheet1.Range("$C$" & r1).Value <> "" Then

            ' Get the formula for the current C cell
            temp = Replace(Sheet1.Range("$C$" & r1).Formula, "=", "")

            ' Create an array by splitting the formula on the + sign
            arTemp = Split(temp, "+")

            Sheet1.Range("$C$" & r1).Value = _
                "=" & Sheet1.Range(arTemp(0)).Value & "+" & _
                Sheet1.Range(arTemp(1)).Value


        End If

    Next

End Sub
```